Capitalize a string in Azure Data explorer
Given a string in Azure Data Explorer, how can I easily capitalize it (change first letter to capital case)?
let Table = datatable(text: string)[
"hello",
"world"
];
Table

expected result:
Hello
World


Inline:
let Table = datatable(text: string)[
"hello",
"world"
];
Table | project text=strcat(toupper(substring(text, 0, 1)), substring(text, 1))

Or, alternativly, create a function:
.create function Capitalize(v: string) {
    strcat(toupper(substring(v, 0, 1)), substring(v, 1))
}

Relevent docs: substring, toupper, strcat
